# How can I add this directive to my application?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to try using this directive:

```
appModule.directive('scrollpane', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.addClass('scroll-pane');
            element.jScrollPane();
            var api = element.data('jsp');
            scope.$watch(function () { return element.find('.' + attrs.scrollpane).length }, function (length) {
                api.reinitialise();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I think I already correctly added the jQuery and other scripts. Can someone tell me how I would call this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to use this on a DIV:

```
<div scrollpane>Contents...</div>
```

The restriction to 'A' means you want to use your directive as an attribute.

Comment: Thanks. When I use VS2013 this gives me a green underline below scrollpane. Is there something I can do to make that go away?

Comment: That is just a "warning" because Visual Studio doesn't understand where the scrollpane attribute comes from -- it is not standard HTML after all. In Options --> Text Editor --> C# --> Advanced, I believe you can turn off live errors and warnings.

Comment: @Melina You can use `data-scrollpane=''` as well and, since this is valid html5, you will have no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the `appModule` is your main module.

You can see on line 3 that this directive is restrict to an attribute (`restrict: 'A'`).

So, all you have to do is create a html element with this attribute.

```
<div scrollpane></div>
```